The rationale for the payoff function of the CHSH game
The payoff of the CHSH game is the characteristic function $\mathbf 1(x\cdot y=(a+b \mod 2))$. What is the rationale for picking this particular payoff function? Is it a consequence of the CHSH inequality? Do we have freedom to choose other forms?

Indeed, it's simply a convenient way to recover the CHSH inequality which is often written as
$$\langle A_0B_0\rangle+\langle A_0B_1\rangle+\langle A_1B_0\rangle-\langle A_1B_1\rangle\leq 2\sqrt{2},$$ where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are quantum observables and $\langle A_iB_j\rangle=\langle \psi|A_i\otimes B_j|\psi\rangle$ is just convenient notation for when the context of the operators and quantum state are clear.
TL;DR One picks the payoff for the game this way because the CHSH inequality is known to allow for a test of genuine quantum correlations (i.e. a separation between the quantum and classical values of the above expression). One has the freedom to choose other payoffs or rules but they won't likely have the classical vs. quantum separation that exists in CHSH/XOR game case. The CHSH game is typically considered the simplest example where this phenomenon occurs.
More details:
In the CHSH game, the probability of winning is given by
$$p_{win}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x,y}\sum_{a,b}\mathbf{1}_{x\cdot y=a\oplus b}p(a,b|x,y),$$ where $a,b,x,y$ are all bits i.e. in $\{0,1\}$, $\mathbf{1}_{x\cdot y=a\oplus b}$ is the Boolean rule (or "payoff") function, and $p(a,b|x,y)$ is the probability of the players responding with $(a,b)$ conditioned on obtaining questions $(x,y)$. We also assumed the questions are asked uniformly (with probability $1/4$).
Maximizing the winning probability is equivalent to maximizing the $bias$ which is defined as $p_{win}-p_{lose}$. If a quantum strategy consists of a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ on a Hilbert space, along with spatially separated projective measurements $\{P_{a|x}\otimes I\}$ and $\{I\otimes Q_{b|y}\}$ resp. then we see that
$$p_{win}-p_{lose}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x,y}(-1)^{x\cdot y}\sum_{a,b}(-1)^{a\oplus b}\langle \psi|P_{a|x}\otimes Q_{b|y}|\psi\rangle\\=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x,y}(-1)^{x\cdot y}\langle \psi|\sum_a(-1)^a P_{a|x}\otimes \sum_b (-1)^b Q_{b|y}|\psi\rangle.$$
Setting $A_x=\sum_a(-1)^a P_{a|x}$ and $B_y=\sum_b (-1)^b Q_{b|y}$ to be the $\pm1$-valued observables we see that the bias can be expressed as
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\langle\psi|A_0\otimes B_0|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|A_1\otimes B_0|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|A_0\otimes B_1|\psi\rangle-\langle\psi|A_1\otimes B_1|\psi\rangle\right),$$
which is precisely the CHSH inequality (scaled by 1/4), it follows that the CHSH game has quantum bias bounded by $1/\sqrt{2}$ and classical bias bounded by $1/2$.

I think it is worth noting that the bias picture can be just seen as modifying the scoring condition of the game. I.e, instead of lose giving a score of $0$ you say that lose gives a score of $-1$, they can both be seen as games. Moreover, the expected scores are affinely related, if $s$ is your Bell-inequality value and $\omega$ is your CHSH game score then you have
$$
s = 8 \omega - 4
$$

Indeed I didn't mention that if $\beta$ is the bias and $\omega$ the win prob, then $\beta=p_{win}-p_{lose}=\omega-(1-\omega)=2\omega-1$.

Good explanation. What variables are you maximizing over when you say "maximizing the bias"?

The maximization of the winning probability is over the set of correlations $p(a,b|x,y)$. This translates in the quantum case to maximizing over quantum states and measurements. In the case of the bias, it means maximizing over $\pm1$-valued observables $A_i$ and $B_j$ and quantum states $|\psi\rangle$ (which implicitly means also maximizing over all spaces $\mathbb{C}^d$).
